# What is a pagination cursor & how can I use it

Tags: php, square-connect

I am trying to retrieve a list of customers using the square PHP SDK. If I leave the `$cursor` blank, I can see a list of all of my customer information. How do I use the pagination cursor to receive a customer by their name? Sample code below:

```
<?php
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

    // Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2
    SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');

    $api_instance = new SquareConnect\Api\CustomersApi();
    // string | A pagination cursor returned by a previous call to this endpoint. 
    //Provide this to retrieve the next set of results for your original query.  
    //See [Paginating results](#paginatingresults) for more information.
    $cursor = "cursor_example"; 
    try {
        $result = $api_instance->listCustomers($cursor);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling CustomersApi->listCustomers: '
                 , $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pagination cursor does not allow you to query for customers by name. If you have more than one "page" of customer, then it allows for you to get more customers by providing a token representing the next page.

If you have enough customers to fill multiple pages, a cursor would be returned in the response.